# Angular ng-submit only allow function in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, submit

In angular js , does html have access to functions not define in $scope ?

For example

Here is controller

```
function TestController($location, $scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.test2 = test2

    $scope.test1 = function(){
      console.log("testing");
    };


    function test2(){
      console.log("what is going on");

    }

  }
```

Here is html that work

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" id="whatup">
  <form ng-submit="test1()">
      <input class="form-control col-lg-8" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="email"></input>
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

If I change `test1()` to `test2()` , the code no longer worked, is there a reason for this?

Do I have to expose `test2()` through alternative ways such as defining it in route?

```
function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/test', {
    controller: 'TestController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: 'templates/test.html'
    }).otherwise('/');
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `vm.test2 = test2` ?

Comment: yup, it was a typo, good catch

Comment: putting this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option for you is creating your `test2` function directly into a controller variable:

```
function TestController($location, $scope, Authentication){
  var vm = this;

  $scope.test1 = function(){
    console.log("testing");
  };


  vm.test2 = function (){
    console.log("what is going on");
  };
}
```

you could also adjust you html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm" id="whatup">
  <form ng-submit="vm.test2()">
      <input class="form-control col-lg-8" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="email"></input>
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this.propOrMethod in your controller code then you are able to get this in the view by using ControllerAs syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as testController">
   {{testController.propOrMethod}}
</div>
```

---

Recommendation:

Don't confuse your code yourself by using both method the `$scope way` and the `this.propOrMethod way`. Anyway you can use both if you like to use them in different div like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as testController">
   {{testController.propOrMethod}} <!-- this.propOrMethod-->
</div>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
   {{propOrMethod}} <!--$scope.propOrMethod-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the () as it is executing in the `this` rather should be a fn

change `vm.test2 = test2()` to `vm.test2 = test2`